sudo chown: pemission denied even if I'm the owner
Could someone explain this?
john@john-pcRefs:~/pCloudDrive/someFolder$ ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 john john  4096 Jan 11  2022 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 john john  4096 Jan 11  2022 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john 10439 Sep 22 18:48 EnvironmentSetup.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john  3370 Mar 25  2023 GitInitialization.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john   342 Jul 10  2023 InitDatabase.sh
john@john-pcRefs:~/pCloudDrive/someFolder$ echo $USER
john
john@john-pcRefs:~/pCloudDrive/someFolder$ sudo chmod +x GitInitialization.sh 
chmod: cannot access 'GitInitialization.sh': Permission denied

If it can help, I'm working on a cloud drive and I've just gone from Ubuntu 22 to Ubuntu 24.

Can you try again without sudo?  When executing something with sudo you’re not executing it as “yourself “.

I got no error message but the job's not done

Please update your question with more information about the particular file system you’re using. Is it a network mounted file system? On the server that is hosting the files , is it a Unix file system or a Windows file system?

Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

In addition to the other comments, does your user have modify access to the parent directory known as someFolder?

The path is includes the word "cloud", so is this perhaps some sort of cloud-based file system? Are you sure it supports UNIX style permissions?

@terdon: yes, it worked on Ubuntu 22

@NasirRiley: yes I've already modified and saved a file with this user

@waltinator: it's done, everything is at drwxr-xr-x except /home/john which is at drwxr-x---

Is this "cloud" file system mounted using FUSE? What is the output of mount | grep pCloudDrive?

@muru: pCloud.fs on /home/john/pCloudDrive type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)


I'm working on a cloud drive

john@john-pcRefs:~/pCloudDrive/someFolder$

I guess you mean this one: https://www.pcloud.com/
Because you're working with a remote (cloud drive) share, you are restricted by what the remote server allows you to do on your cloud drive account.
Also, the pCloud drive apparently emulates a very simple filesystem, similar to FAT32, with no way to store full Unix-style file permissions for each individual file. This is not directly documented, but note that their Frequently Asked Questions webpage says:


Windows reports that pCloud Drive file system is FAT 32. Does it mean that the drive has the file size limitations of this system?

No, there is absolutely no size limits for the files you add in pCloud Drive, regardless of the Operating System.

So it is not exactly FAT32, but apparently the pCloud drive won't store Windows NTFS-style ACLs either. It looks like the designers of pCloud have chosen to make pCloud filesystem with just a very limited file/directory permissions scheme, but with advanced snapshot/crypto features. That design choice will also limit what is possible to do with Linux commands like chown, chgrp and chmod when operating on a cloud filesystem.

Ok but how is it that I could run EnvironmentSetup.sh before going to Ubuntu 24? The permissions are not supposed to change in the process, are they?

OK I know: on Ubuntu 22 I had made the synchronization with a local file and I had forgotten o Ubuntu 24.

Could you create any file? Maybe whole disk/direcory gone read-only. You chan check this with mount command.
Another possible reason is that the file has set "immutable" attribute. You can check this with lsattr command.
Here is the example:
[pw@dell:~/workspace/dir]$ ll
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x  2 pw users 4,0K 09-23 07:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 pw users 4,0K 09-23 07:15 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 pw users    5 09-23 07:20 file1
-rw-r--r--  1 pw users    0 09-23 07:15 file2

[pw@dell:~/workspace/dir]$ lsattr
----i---------e------- ./file2
--------------e------- ./file1

[pw@dell:~/workspace/dir]$ echo "test" > file1

[pw@dell:~/workspace/dir]$ echo "test" > file2
-bash: file2: Operation not permitted


I can create files, mount returns 'rw' but lsattr returns "Operation not supported While reading flags". We got something I guess. I read on internet that it's what happens for symbolic links, but I still don't find how to solve the problem.
